# Click button to select text in input is not working

Tags: javascript

text is not selected in js tried all methods in. `select()` and `btn.select()` in not selecting the text in textbox

```js
        var in = document.getElementById("in");
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    
        btn.onclick() = function(){
            in.focus();
            in.select();
            in.setSelectionRange(0,9999);
             document.execCommand("copy");
        };
```

```html
    <body>
        <input id="in" type="text">
        <button id="btn" >Copy </button>
    </body>
```

Comment: How can this code possibly run when you have a variable named `in`?

Comment: actually im a new to js im working in python ML done mini automation so.... hope u understand my situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` is a reserved key in javascript so cant use it and you have to remove `()` after the onclick when you want to assign it to value.

```js
            var inputField = document.getElementById("in");
            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        
            btn.onclick = function(){
                inputField.focus();
                inputField.select();

                inputField.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
                document.execCommand("copy");
            };
            
            var linkTag = document.getElementById("link");
            var btnLink = document.getElementById("btn-link");

        btnLink .onclick = function(){
            const range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(linkTag );
            const selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);

            document.execCommand('copy');
        };
```

```html
        <body>
            <div>
                <input id="in" type="text">
                 <button id="btn" >Copy </button>
             </div>
            <div>
                 <a href="google.com" id="link">google.com</a>
                 <button id="btn-link" >Copy </button>
             </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: ok but now i hv to copy the text from "a href" how to do tat? <body>
        <a href="https://www.google.com" id="in">google.com</a>
        <button id="btn" >Copy </button>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inP = document.getElementById("in");
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

        btn.onclick = function(){
            inP.focus();
            inP.select();
            inP.setSelectionRange(0,9999);

            document.execCommand("copy");
        };
    </script>

Comment: I added the way to do it with href. try it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. `in` is a reserved word in js, so you can't use it as a variable name.
2. You're wrong at setting onclick event for button

```
btn.onclick() = function(){ // there should not have '()' after onclick
...
```

You should check the error on console when code executed.